# Error: cannot find symbol - on every command

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

Out of curiosity, I decided to play with **[JShell](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/entry/jshell_and_relp_in_java)**.
Now, I'm going through these [Examples](http://geophile.com/jshell/downloads/0.2/jshell.html)

And I can't figure out how to use it. I'm using the [JDK 9 - 108 build](https://jdk9.java.net/download/)
and the simple Linux shell commands doesn't seem to work. I tried `ls`, `cd`, `mkdir` and all I get is:

> Error: cannot find symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples are for something completely different than the [JShell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8) shipped with [Java 9](https://www.oracle.com/java/java9.html). From the [first section of the page you link to](http://geophile.com/jshell/downloads/0.2/jshell.html#section1):

> JShell is a UNIX-like shell written in Java, and intended primarily for working with Java programs. It was written to overcome the problems in working with Java on the Psion 5mx:

The JShell shipped with Java 9 is not meant to interact with the operating system but to throw Java snippets at a running JVM and this try out things. From your other link:

> REPL  allows you to evaluate code snippets such as declarations, statements, expressions. You can test your code as you create it, and way before you are done with your whole project.

So this is just an unfortunate name clash.

Robert Field (designer of the **real** JShell) gave a great introduction to it at Devoxx. See it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jziVaht480w) if you can spare an hour.